# Bing API - Batch job of driving durations and distances

Tags: c#, bing-maps, bing, bing-api

I'm looking towards those with experience batching jobs using the Bing API. I have been able to batch addresses and return geocodes using sample code from Microsoft's [Bing Spatial Data Services](/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701734.aspx) documentation, but haven't been able to batch 'Routes' in order to get driving durations between two addresses or two sets of geo locations. Below is the http query to get durations as a single query followed by the sample function to batch queries.

Edit:
I imagine that by swapping 'geocode' for 'Routes' in this snippet would be an intuitive way (if it is even supported in batch mode):

```
    //Build the HTTP URI that will upload and create the geocode dataflow job
    UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("http://spatial.virtualearth.net");
    uriBuilder.Path = "/REST/v1/dataflows/geocode";
    uriBuilder.Query = queryStringBuilder.ToString();
```

Thanks for any pointers, examples, links showing how to batch routes with the Bing API. (Note: A Bing key is required in order to run below URL.)

Route URL:

http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Routes/Driving?wp.0=Minneapolis,MN&wp.1=St%20Paul,MN&optmz=distance&rpo=Points&key=BingMapsKey

Batch Job for Address-to-Geocodes:

```
static string CreateJob(string dataFilePath, string dataFormat, string key, string description)
{
        string contentType = "text/plain";
        if (dataFormat.Equals("xml", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            contentType = "application/xml";

        StringBuilder queryStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        queryStringBuilder.Append("input=").Append(Uri.EscapeUriString(dataFormat));
        queryStringBuilder.Append("&");
        queryStringBuilder.Append("key=").Append(Uri.EscapeUriString(key));

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(description))
        {
            queryStringBuilder.Append("&");
            queryStringBuilder.Append("description=").Append(Uri.EscapeUriString(description));
        }

        //Build the HTTP URI that will upload and create the geocode dataflow job
        UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("http://spatial.virtualearth.net");
        uriBuilder.Path = "/REST/v1/dataflows/geocode";
        uriBuilder.Query = queryStringBuilder.ToString();

        //Include the data to geocode in the HTTP request
        using (FileStream dataStream = File.OpenRead(dataFilePath))
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriBuilder.Uri);

            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = contentType;

            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
                int bytesRead = dataStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                while (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                    bytesRead = dataStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
            }

            //Submit the HTTP request and check if the job was created successfully. 
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Created)
                    throw new Exception("An HTTP error status code was encountered when creating the geocode job.");

                string dataflowJobLocation = response.GetResponseHeader("Location");
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataflowJobLocation))
                    throw new Exception("The 'Location' header is missing from the HTTP response when creating a goecode job.");

                return dataflowJobLocation;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Did ever find a way of doing this? I need to find driving distances from a postcode to around 150 locations in the UK to find the nearest 5. This is in a webpage that gets thousands of visits a day. So it needs to be efficient and fast. The accepted answer sounds like a poor compromise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bing Maps doesn't have a batch service for getting routing distance/times, however, you can use the REST routing service to make multiple calls to do this. One optimization you can make to speed things up is to use multiple waypoints in a single request. Bing Maps allows up to 25 waypoints in a single request. For example, if you wanted to get the route distances from A to B and A to C you could create a single route request that goes from A to B to A to C and then loop through the route legs in the response. All the route legs that have an even number index will be from A to a destination. You can then grab the distance and time for just that leg.

You will need to use this service: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701705.aspx

You can find information on how to use this service in .NET here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819168.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj870778.aspx

Comment: I was afraid of that as I couldn't find any mention of 'Routes' in the Dataflows docs. Interesting advice about using waypoints. Thanks!